# Python type hint in inherited class

Tags: python, types, python-typing

I have a small piece of code

```py
from threading import Timer
from time import sleep

class RepeatTimer(Timer):

    def run(self):
        while not self.finished.wait(self.interval):
            self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)



def nudge():
    print('This is a reminder')

remind = RepeatTimer(1,nudge)
remind.start()
sleep(5)
remind.cancel()
```

The code runs and what the code does is not so important here. But in vscode a error message is thrown for `Pylance(reportGeneralTypeIssues)`

```
"Cannot access member \"finished\" for type \"RepeatTimer\"\n  Member \"finished\" is unknown",
"Cannot access member \"interval\" for type \"RepeatTimer\"\n  Member \"interval\" is unknown",
"Cannot access member \"function\" for type \"RepeatTimer\"\n  Member \"function\" is unknown",
"Cannot access member \"args\" for type \"RepeatTimer\"\n  Member \"args\" is unknown",
"Cannot access member \"kwargs\" for type \"RepeatTimer\"\n  Member \"kwargs\" is unknown",
```

So, how do I fix this? How to properly type annotate the `self` here so it actually can detect that these are the members of the class `Timer`.

Comment: Hm, I wonder what Pylance is doing. None of those attributes are *documented*, but they are clearly defined  by [`Timer.__init__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/threading.py#L1356).

Comment: I wonder if the stub file for `threading.py` (if such a thing exists) somehow blocks Pylance from using them. `threading.py` itself doesn't use any type annotations, so the attributes may be "private" as far as Pylance is concerned, and not visible for use by a subclass.

Comment: Rather than messing with `Timer` "internals", you might try subclassing `Thread` to repeatedly create and run separate timers using the same function. (`Timer` as written doesn't look to be reusable. You can start it and cancel it, but not resume it.)